# How to change data from model for different controllers in XCode 4.2

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am fairly new to Objective-C and iOS programming, and I am having lots of trouble passing data around. I have created a model "LevelsCompleted" where I have declared an `NSString` property:

```
@property (readwrite,copy) NSString *answersString;
```

I synthesized it in the .m file:

```
@synthesize answersString = _answersString;
```

Now if I change its value in one of my controllers

```
-(void) changeAnswersString{
    LevelsCompleted *lvls = [[LevelsCompleted alloc] init];
    [lvls setAnswersString:@"1"];
}
```

And then access it from a third controller:

```
-(void) showAnswerStringValue{
    LevelsCompleted *lvls = [[LevelsCompleted alloc]init];
    NSLog(@"%@", [lvls answersString]);
}
```

The console prints *null* instead of *1*

I really can't find a way to change data for every controller, and my english is very limited so I don't know what to search for in documentation. Any help please?

**Actual Code**

//  PuzzleOneViewController.m

```
#import "PuzzleOneViewController.h"
#import "LevelChooseViewController.h"

@interface PuzzleOneViewController(){
int thinInt;
int i;
int answer[10];
bool validSubmit, miniPresent, toDelete;
}
@end

@implementation PuzzleOneViewController

@synthesize levels;

- (IBAction)backButton:(id)sender {
if (levels ==nil) self.levels = [[LevelsCompleted alloc]init];
self.levels.answersString=@"Hello";
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];


}

@end
```

//  PuzzleOneViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "LevelsCompleted.h"

@interface PuzzleOneViewController : UIViewController{
BOOL grosseur;
NSString *choice;
IBOutlet UIScrollView *sv;
IBOutlet UILabel *cluesLabel;
IBOutlet UILabel *hintLabelText;
   }

@property (nonatomic, retain) LevelsCompleted *levels;

- (IBAction)backButton:(id)sender;

@end
```

//  LevelsCompleted.h   THIS IS MY MODEL

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface LevelsCompleted : NSObject
{
int hello;
BOOL success[30];
NSString *answersString;
}
@property (readwrite,copy) NSString *answersString;

-(BOOL) success:(int)number;
-(void) setSuccess:(BOOL)result atIndex:(int)number;
@end
```

//  LevelsCompleted.m

```
#import "LevelsCompleted.h"

@implementation LevelsCompleted
@synthesize answersString;

-(BOOL) success:(int)number{
    return success[number];
}
-(void) setSuccess:(BOOL)result atIndex:(int)number{
    success[number] = result;
}
@end
```

//  LevelChooseViewController.m

```
#import "LevelChooseViewController.h"
#import "LevelsCompleted.h"
#import "PuzzleOneViewController.h"

@implementation LevelChooseViewController


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

PuzzleOneViewController *controller = [[PuzzleOneViewController alloc]init];

NSLog(@"%@",controller.levels.answersString);   // prints NULL
NSLog(@"%@", PuzzleOneViewController.levels.answersString); // Generates Error


}


-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"PassLevelA"]){
    [[segue destinationViewController] setChoice:_levelChoice];

}
}

- (IBAction)Level1Choose:(id)sender {

_levelChoice = [[sender currentTitle]intValue];
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"PassLevelA" sender:self];
}
@end
```

And nothing interesting in the LevelChooseViewController.h file...
I could not copy everything because my controllers have 500+ lines of code each, but I but everything relevant (i hope so...) Thanks a lot for helping

Comment: Is your LevelsCompleted an instance of `NSManagedObject`? If so, you are not supposed to create its instances by `alloc init`, you should use `[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName: inManagedObjectContext:]` instead

Comment: It is an instance of `NSObject`, but should I change it to `NSManagedObject` instead for what I want to do to work?

Comment: Did you actually copy/paste this code? `#import "SecondController.m"` is wrong. It should be `#import "SecondController.h"`. Further, it's odd to give a variable a name beginning with a capital letter ("PuzzleOneViewController"). That said, and assuming you actually import SecondController.h I don't immediately see a reason for the error you report.

Comment: Yes sorry, my initial code is in french so I had to translate it.. I import secondController.h . Thanks for letting me know not to name my classes with capital letters, but I really have no idea why I am getting this error

Comment: If you don't mind, just post your actual code. It's no problem that it's French.

Comment: Just posted it, thanks a lot for staying to help

Comment: The problem is really still the same. `PuzzleOneViewController *controller = [[PuzzleOneViewController alloc]init];` creates a new PuzzleOneViewController which has nothing to do with the one you are trying to access. The reason `NSLog(@"%@", PuzzleOneViewController.levels.answersString);` generates an error is that you're trying to access the levels property on the `PuzzleOneViewController` _class_, rather than an instance of the class. These errors suggest that your understanding of Object Oriented Programming in general and Objective-C specifically needs work... Are you working from a book?

Comment: I decided to use a static variable instead, and everything works fine! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not accessing the same LevelsCompleted object instance. `[[LevelsCompleted alloc] init]` creates a new LevelsCompleted instance. This is a separate object from the LevelsCompleted object you created in your changeAnswersString method. In order to access that levels completed object from the "third controller", you need to come up with a way to share data between the two controllers. Without knowing the overall structure of your program, it's hard to say exactly what you should do, but one easy option is to add a "levels" @property to your first controller, or maybe your application delegate, that way you can access it from other places:

In your FirstController.h:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) LevelsCompleted *levels;
```

In your FirstController.m:

```
@synthesize levels;
```

Then, in changeAnswersString:

```
- (void)changeAnswersString
{
    if (self.levels == nil) self.levels = [[LevelsCompleted alloc] init];
    self.levels.answersString = @"1";
}
```

Now, in showAnswerStringValue:

```
- (void)showAnswerStringValue
{
    NSLog(@"%@", firstController.levels.answersString);
}
```

As always, you should think carefully about the structure of your program. It's impossible to convey all the things to consider in a short answer like this one, but I'd recommend reading up on standard Cocoa design patterns, particularly Model View Controller (MVC) paradigm.

Comment: Thank you very much, this should work; it was silly for me to forget that two different objects are created! Very good answer

Comment: I get an error saying that property 'levels' is not found on object of type 'FirstController'.. And if I create a FirstController object, the console of course prints 'null'; Is the 'levels' property not declared the right way?

Comment: I'm not sure without looking at your new code. Edit your question and add your new code...